# FastAPI doesn't include a JSON content type in the header, if a trailing slash is in the URL

Tags: api, fastapi

Depending on whether or not my URL has a trailing slash in it, [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) (with uvicorn server), will omit a `content type: application/json` header. I'm worried that clients might inadvertently put in a trailing slash in their URLs, and then not get back a JSON response, so I'd like to know

a) Is this correct behaviour?

b) How do I handle it server side?

Here is a very simple FastAPI application:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

app.get("/alist")
async def alist():
    somelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return somelist
```

Now here is what the headers look like for the "correct" request, namely one without a trailing slash:

[image]

Because WITH a trailing slash, the content-type: application/json is missing, and this can confuse the client.

[image]

So as per my question above, is this normal? And what do I do about it to prevent errors from clients expecting JSON response but which inadvertently added a trailing slash?

Comment: The response you are looking at is actually a redirection (HTTP status code 307). So the behavior looks like expected.
A second request is then triggered to the URL without the trailing slash.

Comment: @AdrienMatissart but if a second request is made without the slash, why doesn't Firefox treat its result as JSON and format it as such? See how in the first screenshot, Firefox's jsonview has formatted the response nicely as JSON, whereas in the second, though the resulting data is the same, the JSONview addin hasn't seen it as JSON? That's what I'm worried about. Client applications won't see it as JSON if it has a trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Is this correct behavior?

- This behavior appears because of redirection (HTTP status code 307).
- I think this should be handled automatically.
- So I think we should open a new issue in [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) repo.

b) How do I handle it server-side?

There are many different solutions :

1 - By converting the list to dict using one key trick (simple solution) :

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

app.get("/alist")
async def alist():
    somelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return {"numbers": somelist}
```

2 - By adding "content-type" header manually :

using Response :

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()

app.get("/alist")
async def alist(response: Response):
    # set content-type header to application/json
    response.headers["content-type"] = "application/json"
    somelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return somelist
```

using JSONResponse :

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()

app.get("/alist")
async def alist():
    somelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    # you can add additional headers
    headers = {"X-Cat-Dog": "alone in the world", "Content-Language": "en-US"}
    # json response will enforce "content-type" header to be "application/json"
    return JSONResponse(content=somelist, headers=headers)
```

You can read more about FastAPI responses and headers at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers/